# Coloring heat map, with custom characteristics

Tags: color, heat-map

I need to color a "heat map", with these characteristics: "Pseudocolor monoband", "Discrete" and with two levels:

1. <= "STATISTICS_MEAN" -> Color 255/255/255
2. "Inf" -> Color 196/255/185

I have to do it in different "heat maps" and I want to do it with the "Graphic Modeler".
How can I do it?.

[image]
[image]